# How to plot a Histogram in jython using ptolemy?

Tags: plot, jython, histogram

Does anyone know how to plot an array of float numbers, 30 elements, as a histogram with ptolemy in Jython?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
from javax.swing import JButton, JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, JMenuBar
from java.awt import GridBagLayout,GridBagConstraints
from java.awt import BorderLayout as BorderLayout
from javax.swing import WindowConstants
from ptolemy import * 
from ptolemy.plot import Plot as Plot
from RainfallAnalysis import  RainfallAnalysis
from jarray import array;

class Histogram(Plot):
    dataset = 0;
    theJFrame = JFrame();
    def __init__(self):
        self.theJFrame.setSize(400, 350);                 #outer box
        self.setSize(350, 300);                      #graph window
        self.setButtons(True);                       #buttons to print, edit, etc.
        self.setMarksStyle("none");                  #do not show marks at points
    ##
    #  Draw a histogram.
    #  It is assumed that all bins are of equal size.
    #  @param name The name to give this histogram in the key
    #  @param xMin minimum of x-range covered by histogram
    #  @param xMax maximum of x-range covered by histogram
    #  @param y    array of bin heights; length of array is used to give number of      points

    def drawHistogram(self,name, xMin, xMax,y):
        binWidth = (xMax - xMin)/y.__len__();
        self.setBars(binWidth,0.0);
        self.setConnected(False);               # do not join bars with a line
        first = True;
        self.setYLabel("Rain Measurement");
        self.setXLabel("days"); 
        for i in range(y.__len__()):                #loop to add bars to plot
            x = i 
            self.addPoint(self.dataset, x, y[i], not first);
            first = False;   
        self.addLegend(self.dataset, name);
        self.dataset = self.dataset+1;

    def showIt(self):
        gridbag = GridBagLayout();
        c = GridBagConstraints();
        self.theJFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridbag);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(self, c);
        self.theJFrame.getContentPane().add(self);
        self.theJFrame.setVisible(True);
        self.theJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h    = Histogram();
    rf   = RainfallAnalysis();
    min  = rf.getMin();
    max  = rf.getMax();
    data = rf.getData();
    h.drawHistogram("rainfall",min,max,data);
    h.showIt();
```

And data is simply and array of double numbers.